Flavor specific AndroidManifest with HOME intent
On Android, I am trying to give a specific flavor the HOME intent in order to be able to configure it as Launcher (load that app when Home button is pressed).
I have left the flavor's AndroidManifest.xml with only that intent for the Main Activity. The rest of intents are in the common Manifest.
The manifest merge seems to happen correctly but the HOME intent does not seem to be picked, as the app is not allowing the Launcher feature (i.e. does not show up in the "Default Apps" menu as an option for launchers).
